# Which sentence is right

Tags: grammar

"Have you read about the latest royal scandal?

No, don`t you believe **all** (or **all what**?) you read in the papers, do you?"

Which one is correct?

Comment: What do you think? This SE is about helping people to learn English, so it's very helpful if questions actually show your thinking, what research you've done (looking up references, searching for phrases on Google and so on), what you're struggling with, in order to give you an answer that actually helps you learn an underlying concept or rule.

Comment: First of all, there are some other issues with the sentence. If you're going to end it with *do you* and phrase it as a question, I would make the sentence start with *you don't* not *don't you*. Without that change (or something similar), neither version is grammatical.